# XHTML, how not to display the TITLE attribute as a tooltip

Tags: html, xhtml

To make my web site XHTML compliant, I have added a `title` attribute to all of my `IMG` tags.

However, when you mouseover an image, the text from my `title` attribute displays as a small popup. I don't want that text to be viewable.

**Question**: How do I prevent the browser from displaying the `title` attribute text as a popup while still keeping the `title` attribute present?

```
<img src="..." title="text that gets displayed as a popup but I don't want it to" />
```

Comment: It's called a tooltip, not a popup.

Comment: What's the use case? i.e. what type of data are you putting in the title, why are you putting it there, and why shouldn't it appear as a tooltip? Your first sentence suggests you added the attributes based on the notion that the title attribute is required for XHTML conformance — it isn't. If it isn't the right tool, don't use it.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to have a `title` to be compliant, you need an `alt`.

The behaviour you are seeing is the correct implementation by the UA of title so is hard/impossible to override.

Comment: I was just typing this when SO showed me a bar to load new answers, and then you saved me from typing the rest. :D
Beware, though, that IE6 (I'm not sure about IE7/8 behavior) do show alt attributes as tooltips, just like title.

Answer (score 4):

This is browser specific. Some browsers choose to display the title attribute, some choose not to display anything, and some even choose to display the alt attribute instead. Though lately this has become more uniform across browsers, with most of them leaning to the title attribute..

Answer (score 2):

Title is meant to be shown, if you want an image description that does not show except for screen readers, use the alt attribute which is only shown if the image cannot be displayed (=> Screen readers).

Comment: Alt is not limited to screen readers. Don't forget about text browsers. And graphical browsers with images turned off. And braille readers. And search engines. etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ALT` and `TITLE` together. Put your nice, helpful text in the alt tag and then nothing in the title tag [like so](http://jsbin.com/ohepa):

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"o 
     alt="Goooooooogle!"
     title="" />
```

If `ALT` is no longer "valid" (is it?!), I suggest that any solution around this slight validation annoyance will be far worse than ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a great solution, living with the tooltip is better, but if you set an absolutely positioned div with a solid background set to very low opacity (1%) and a higher z-index then your image, you should not get a tooltip.

```
 <img style="position:absolute;
             top:0;left:0;width:200px;height:200px;"
       src="yourImage.gif" alt="the text you don't want to show" 
                           title="the text you don't want to show"/> 
 <div style="position:absolute;
             top:0;left:0;height:200px;width:200px;
             z-index:1000;filter:alpha(opacity=01);
             -moz-opacity:0.01;background-color:gray;">
 </div>
```

Again, I don't suggest this, but this is just to show that there is a way...

Comment: @mu is too short - I'm going to need another one now that you've reminded me of it again :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since this post, but I figure for all those who wander here from Google, here's my 2 cents:

The alt tag is fully valid--required even.  The last solution works in nearly every browser, and where it doesn't work, a tiny rectangular tooltip will be shown with no text.  The title tag overrides the alt tag and forces a specific tooltip to be shown.  I don't know why people voted this down, considering it's the best solution here.

For those of you who see this as a bad markup: for a general website, yes, this isn't good practice.  This is a modern age of the web, however, and you have to also consider web applications and very obscure one-off situations where this might be the best possible solution given the markup options we have to work with.  We all know web 2.0 is only MOSTLY there.  ;)

PROPOSED ALTERNATIVE:
Personally, I would suggest creating a div the size of the image and setting its background-image to the src that you want to use.  There is DEFINITELY no tooltip this way, regardless of browser, and it's 100% compliant with everything.  This will not work if it's an inline image, but it's pretty rare to use an image inline with text and not want a tooltip (an icon beside links, for instance, a great tooltip might be "External Link", or for a mailto:, "Send an email to:", etc.)